# Converting a for loop to a while loop yielding different than expected results

Tags: java, loops

**Situation:**

I am trying to convert the following for loop into a while loop:

```
final int MIN = 1;
final int MAX = 7;
int i=MIN,j=MIN;

for(i=MIN; i<=MAX;i++)
{
    for(j=MIN;j<=MAX;j++)
    {
        if(i==j)
            if(i==(MIN+MAX)/2)
                System.out.print("o");
            else
                System.out.print("*");
        else if (i+j == MIN+MAX)
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**I thought it was pretty simple:**

```
while(i<=MAX)
{
    while(j<= MAX)
    {
        if(i==j)
            if(i==(MIN+MAX)/2)
                System.out.print("o");
            else
                System.out.print("*");
        else if (i+j == MIN+MAX)
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i++;
}
```

however, for some unknown reason, when i>1, it never goes into the inner while loop. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Use braces (even when they're optional)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time for loop start it gives j value of MIN. While loop doesn't so you have to replace value after cirtucs of loop. If you did not declare `j-MIN;` before inner loop, after fist inner  loop iteration j would be 8 so it is not <=8

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 7;
    int i=MIN,j=MIN;

    while(i<=MAX)
    {
        j=MIN;  //ADDED
        while(j<= MAX)
        {
            if(i==j)
                if(i==(MIN+MAX)/2)
                    System.out.print("o");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            else if (i+j == MIN+MAX)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
    }
```